# Does this version of Clairaut-Schwarz theorem hold when mixed partial derivatives are of order greater than $2$?

Tags: real-analysis

I asked this question on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437400/does-clairaut-schwarz-theorem-hold-when-mixed-partial-derivatives-are-of-order-g). One person gave an answer but then he deleted it because my version of Clairaut-Schwarz theorem is stronger than his. I meant my version only requires the continuity of **one** mixed partial derivative while his may requires the continuity of **all** mixed partial derivatives.

It seems that this question will receive no answer in MSE, so I have no choice but to post it on *mathoverflow.net*.

---

I usually encounter Clairaut-Schwarz theorem where the mixed partial derivatives are of order $2$, i.e.

> $\textbf{Clairaut-Schwarz Theorem:}$ Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$, $f:X \to F$, and $i, j \in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Suppose that $\partial_j \partial_i f$ is continuous at $a$ and that $\partial_j f$ exists in a neighborhood of $a$. Then $\partial_i \partial_j f (a)$ exists and $$\partial_i \partial_j f (a) = \partial_j \partial_i f (a)$$

I would like to ask if Clairaut-Schwarz theorem holds in case the mixed partial derivatives are of arbitrary order $m$, i.e.

> Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$, $f:X \to F$, and $m \in \mathbb N$. Suppose $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_m \in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1, \ldots, m\}$. If $\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f$ is continuous at $a$ and $\partial_{j_{\sigma(2)}}  \cdots \partial_{j_{\sigma(m)}} f$ exists in a neighborhood of $a$, then $$\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)= \partial_{j_{\sigma(1)}} \partial_{j_{\sigma(2)}}  \cdots \partial_{j_{\sigma(m)}} f(a)$$

---

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: +1. To me, trying to understand how standard results can be generalized and how is mathematical research.

Comment: Thank you @DanieleTampieri for your encourage! Honestly, I proved the theorem in case mixed partial derivatives are of order $2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436099/suppose-partial-j-partial-i-f-is-continuous-at-a-and-partial-j-f-exists).

Comment: Doesn’t this follow from the fact that weak partial derivatives commute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f:X\to F$ has the partial derivatives $\partial_m\partial_{m-1}\dots\partial_1f(x)$ at any point $x$ of the open rectangle $X:=\prod_{1\le i\le n}]b_i,c_i[$.

For $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\delta_u $ denote the finite difference $\delta_uf(x):=f(x+u)-f(x)$, defined for $x$ and $x+u\in X$, and let $(e_i)_i$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Iterating the Mean Value Theorem, we have, say with $|t_j|<r$  and $[x_j-r,x_j+r]\subset\; ]b_j,c_j[$ for $j=1\dots m$ 
$$\big\|\delta_{t_me_m}\dots \delta_{t_1e_1}f(x)\big\|_F\le |t_1\dots t_m| \sup_{|x_j-y_j| \le r\atop 1\le j\le m}\big\|\partial_m \dots\partial_1f(y) \big\|_F.$$

If $p\in F$ and we apply the latter to the function $g(x):=f(x)-px_1\dots x_m $ we also get
$$\big\|\delta_{t_me_m}\dots \delta_{t_1e_1}f(x)-p\,t_1\dots t_m\big\|_F\le |t_1\dots t_m| \sup_{|x_j-y_j| \le r\atop 1\le j\le m}\big\|\partial_m \dots\partial_1f(y) -p\big\|_F.$$
In particular if we take $p:=\partial_m \dots\partial_1f(a)$, and we assume that $\partial_m \dots\partial_1f$ is continuous at $x=a$, we have

$$\big\|\frac{ \delta_{t_me_m}\dots \delta_{t_1e_1}f(a)} {t_1\dots t_m} -\partial_m \dots\partial_1f(a)\big\|_F=o(1) $$ for $\|t\|\to0$. Assume now there exists the $(m-1)$-order partial derivative  $\partial_{\sigma_{m-1}}\dots\partial_{\sigma_1}f(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and for a given permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,m\}$. Since all $\delta_ {t_j e_j}$ commute, taking the limit  for $ t_{\sigma_{j}}\to0$ from $j=1$ to $j=m-1$, we arrive at
$$\big\|\frac{\partial_{\sigma_{m-1}}\dots\partial_{\sigma_1}f(a+t_{\sigma_m})-\partial_{\sigma_{m-1}}\dots\partial_{\sigma_1}f(a)} {t_{\sigma_m}} -\partial_m \dots\partial_1f(a)\big\|_F=o(1) $$ for $t_{\sigma_m}\to0,$ 
whence the thesis: there exists $\partial_{\sigma_{m}}\dots\partial_{\sigma_1}f$ at $x=a$ and coincides with $\partial_m \dots\partial_1f(a)$.

(Note: To simplify the notation I assumed $(j_1,\dots,j_m)$ are  $(1,\dots,m)$; nothing changes in general even if some of the $j_k$ coincide, because any mixed derivative can be written $\partial_{j_m}\dots\partial_{j_1}f(a)=\frac{\partial }{\partial s_m}\dots\frac{\partial }{\partial s_1}f(a+s_1e_{j_1}+\dots+s_m e_{j_m})|_{s_1=0\dots s_m=0}$).

Comment: After long time digesting your proof using finite difference operator, I have combined it with my previous attempt to to give my it a try. I have posted my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439436/generalized-clairaut-schwarz-theorem-for-arbitrary-order-of-mixed-partial-deriva). If you don't mind, please have a look at it. Thank you so much! By the way, I'm just exposed to Real Analysis, so your proof is quite advanced for me.

Comment: Could you please explain how to go from $g(x):=f(x)-px_1\dots x_m$ to $\delta_{t_me_m}\dots \delta_{t_1e_1}g(x) = \delta_{t_me_m}\dots \delta_{t_1e_1}f(x)-p\,t_1\dots t_m$?

Comment: The difference operator is linear, so you only need to observe how it acts on $px_1\dots x_m$; just consider the case m=1...

Comment: IHi, are $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ in the expression $g(x):=f(x)-px_1\dots x_m$ constant, or are they dependent on $x$? it seems to me that $x_1,\ldots,x_m \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f$ exists in a neighbourhood of $a$ and it is continuous at $a$. Let $\Delta^h_k f(x) = f(x + h e_k) - f(x)$ be the difference operator, with $e_k$ the $k$-th vector in the standard basis. By Fubini's theorem (and induction),
$$ \Delta_{j_1}^{h_1} \ldots \Delta_{j_m}^{h_m} f(a) = \idotsint\limits_{[0,h_1]\times\ldots\times[0,h_m]} \partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f(a + y) dy_{j_1} \ldots dy_{j_m} ,$$
where we understand that $y_k = 0$ for $k \notin \{j_1, \ldots, j_m\}$. It follows that
$$ \lim_{(h_1, \ldots, h_m) \to 0} \frac{\Delta_{j_1}^{h_1} \ldots \Delta_{j_m}^{h_m} f(a)}{h_1 \ldots h_m} = \partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f(a) .$$
The difference operators commute, and therefore
$$ \lim_{(h_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, h_{\sigma(m)}) \to 0} \frac{\Delta_{j_{\sigma(1)}}^{h_{\sigma(1)}} \ldots \Delta_{j_{\sigma(m)}}^{h_{\sigma(m)}} f(a)}{h_{\sigma(1)} \ldots h_{\sigma(m)}} = \partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f(a) .$$
In particular,
$$ \lim_{h_{\sigma(1)} \to 0} \lim_{(h_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, h_{\sigma(m)}) \to 0} \frac{\Delta_{j_{\sigma(1)}}^{h_{\sigma(1)}} \ldots \Delta_{j_{\sigma(m)}}^{h_{\sigma(m)}} f(a)}{h_{\sigma(1)} \ldots h_{\sigma(m)}} = \partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f(a) ,$$
that is,
$$ \lim_{h_{\sigma(1)} \to 0} \frac{1}{h_{\sigma(1)}} \Delta_{j_{\sigma(1)}}^{h_{\sigma(1)}} \biggl(\lim_{(h_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, h_{\sigma(m)}) \to 0} \frac{\Delta_{j_{\sigma(2)}}^{h_{\sigma(2)}} \ldots \Delta_{j_{\sigma(m)}}^{h_{\sigma(m)}} f(\cdot)}{h_{\sigma(2)} \ldots h_{\sigma(m)}}\biggr)(a) = \partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f(a) .$$
By assumption, the parenthesized expression is equal to $\partial_{j_{\sigma(2)}} \ldots \partial_{j_{\sigma(m)}} f(\cdot)$ in a neighbourhood of $a$, and so finally
$$ \lim_{h_{\sigma(1)} \to 0} \frac{1}{h_{\sigma(1)}} \Delta_{j_{\sigma(1)}}^{h_{\sigma(1)}} \bigl(\partial_{j_{\sigma(2)}} \ldots \partial_{j_{\sigma(m)}} f\bigr)(a) = \partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f(a) ,$$
that is,
$$ \partial_{j_{\sigma(1)}} \partial_{j_{\sigma(2)}} \ldots \partial_{j_{\sigma(m)}} f(a) = \partial_{j_1} \ldots \partial_{j_m} f(a) ,$$
as desired.

Comment: It is a bit delicate the integral of $\partial_{j_1}\dots\partial_{j_m}f$, since a priori it  is just an $F$-valued measurable function, but you want to use Fubini's thm and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: For instance, even in one variable, $f(t):=t^2\sin(t^{-2})$ for $t\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$, is everywhere differentiable but  $f'$ is not  integrable on $[-1,1]$

Comment: @PietroMajer: Wait, here we *assume* that $\partial_{j_1}\ldots\partial_{j_m}f$ is continuous at $a$, and hence bounded (and in particular integrable) in a neighbourhood of $a$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: ok! (maybe it was better to state that the  integral formula is meant for $h_j$ small)